# R Package Installation Error

Tags: r

I am trying to install rpart package in Linux using the following command:

```
    /opt/vertica/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL rpart_4.1-5.tar.gz
```

However I get the following long error message:

```
* installing to library '/home/vertica/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0'
* installing *source* package 'rpart' ...
** package 'rpart' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
cc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/vertica/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic   -c    
anova.c -o anova.o
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:6: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:8: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:24: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:27: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:28: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:36: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:39: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:40: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:43: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:44: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:50: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:51: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:57: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:59: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:131: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:132: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:144: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:146: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:147: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:148: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:323: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:335: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:340: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:344: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:372: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:376: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:380: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:390: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:393: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:420: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:425: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:429: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:433: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:436: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:445: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:452: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:454: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:477: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:481: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:487: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:493: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:499: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:505: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:511: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:561: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:579: Error: 8-byte relocation cannot be applied to 4-byte field
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:592: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:593: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:594: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/tmp/ccw3PpFa.s:595: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
make: *** [anova.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rpart'
* removing '/home/vertica/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rpart'
```

Below is the result of sessionInfo() call in R:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C                 LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Could someone help me with what this error message is about and how to resolve it?

Thank you.

Ravi

Comment: Maybe include in the post the output of `sessionInfo()`, so people can see some of your system/R details. (rpart 4.1-5 installed fine for me using `install.packages('rpart')`)

Comment: Added the sessionInfo() results

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `install.packages` from within R?

Comment: Yes. I get the same error when I install it in R using install.packages command.

Comment: works for me with R-3.0.1 on linux 64 bit (ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14865976/489704) and see if the answer suggested there helps. I notice the same compilation error for `rpart` is reported there.

Comment: (When I said it worked for me, I should have mentioned that I'm running 64-bit R 3.0.2 on Win 8.1)

Comment: I have gcc version 3.4.6 installed? From the link that jbaums gave it appears that atleast version 4.2 is required for R 2.15? Is it true for  R 13.0 as well?

Comment: There is no R.13. But you should by all means update to R 3.0.2 and make sure you are using the recommended compiler. If gcc 4.2 was needed for R 2.15 then at least that version would surely be needed for 3.0.2.

Comment: I meant to say R 3.0.2 not R 13. That was a typo. Let me try with gcc version 4.2

Comment: It worked fine with gcc version 4.8. Thank you.