# gcc compiler fails for R package installation lpSolve

Tags: c++, r, gcc

I am getting an "-Werror=format-security" error when gcc compiles lpSolve in R.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (lubuntu kernel) and R version 3.1.0.

Here is the exact error:

```
   * installing *source* package ‘lpSolve’ ...
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I . -DINTEGERTIME -DPARSER_LP -DBUILDING_FOR_R -DYY_NEVER_INTERACTIVE -DUSRDLL -DCLOCKTIME -DRoleIsExternalInvEngine -DINVERSE_ACTIVE=INVERSE_LUSOL -DINLINE=static -DParanoia     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c colamd.c -o colamd.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I . -DINTEGERTIME -DPARSER_LP -DBUILDING_FOR_R -DYY_NEVER_INTERACTIVE -DUSRDLL -DCLOCKTIME -DRoleIsExternalInvEngine -DINVERSE_ACTIVE=INVERSE_LUSOL -DINLINE=static -DParanoia     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c commonlib.c -o commonlib.o
commonlib.c: In function ‘blockWriteINT’:
commonlib.c:691:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
commonlib.c: In function ‘blockWriteBOOL’:
commonlib.c:710:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
commonlib.c: In function ‘blockWriteREAL’:
commonlib.c:732:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [commonlib.o] Error 1
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I . -DINTEGERTIME -DPARSER_LP -DBUILDING_FOR_R -DYY_NEVER_INTERACTIVE -DUSRDLL -DCLOCKTIME -DRoleIsExternalInvEngine -DINVERSE_ACTIVE=INVERSE_LUSOL -DINLINE=static -DParanoia     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c commonlib.c -o commonlib.o
commonlib.c: In function ‘blockWriteINT’:
commonlib.c:691:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
commonlib.c: In function ‘blockWriteBOOL’:
commonlib.c:710:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
commonlib.c: In function ‘blockWriteREAL’:
commonlib.c:732:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [commonlib.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lpSolve’
* removing ‘/home/ben/lpSolve.Rcheck/lpSolve’
```

I have tried manually installing it using R CMD INSTALL. I've also followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865976/r-packages-fail-to-compile-with-gcc) to no avail.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Consider building with an older `gcc`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs at fprintf in the functions, thus if you download the source code, re-make the package, and it'll be solved. But the lpSolve packing is currently orphaned. The error might occur due to the compiler check. Here's a way to make a detour.

1. Go to R etc path (e.g. /usr/lib/R/etc, or /etc/R).
2. Edit Makeconf file: remove -Werror=format-security in CFLAGS. (It is read-only file, thus su authority is required.)
3. Re-install package: install.package('lpSolve')
4. Restore Makeconf file back if necessary.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Just now the lpSolve package has been updated to 5.6.8, thus there is no problem more to install lpSolve package. The change log can be checked at http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/lpSolve/ChangeLog