# cannot install R "fpc" package on linux

Tags: r, centos, cluster-computing

I am trying to install the `fpc` package on linux os. I got the error:

```
dependencies ‘mclust’, ‘prabclus’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘robustbase’, ‘kernlab’ are not available for package ‘fpc’
```

Then I tried to install `mclust` first, and I got `ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’`

I suspect OS is missing some files, but not sure how to fix. Can anybody help? Many thanks!

Comment: I cant reproduce on ubuntu 14.04, R3.2.2. What distro are you using, what R version, and whar code did you use when trying to install/ thanks

Comment: @user20650 I am using Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.03, R version: R version 3.1.1.  
I used  install.packages("fpc", dependencies=T)

Comment: I would try updating your R version and trying to install again

Comment: Tried so, the version is 3.2.2, and it still has error

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by following the answer here 
[R Packages, gcc, and BLAS on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743321/r-packages-gcc-and-blas-on-amazon-ec2)
In addition, this site is also helpful.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=584481

Thanks for those left comments.