# Installation of Rtools. Can't fnd C++ compiler

Tags: c++, r

I want to use a program called Stan within R. To do so I need to install Rtools to get the C++ compiler. According to the Stan website, I am to check the box for editing path upon installation of Rtools.

For some reason R can't seem to find the compiler.

> Sys.getenv("PATH")
>   [1] "c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin;c:\Rtools\bin;c:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin;c:\R\R-3.2\bin\i386;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32;C:\Users\a3988\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"
>
> system('g++ -v')
>   Warning message:
>   running command 'g++ -v' had status 127
>
> Sys.which("g++")
>                                      g++ 
>   "c:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\G__~1.EXE"

Can anybody help? I am using 
R-version: 3.4.2
Rtools34
Windows10

Comment: What do you get when you type `gcc --help` in the terminal?

Comment: ...in other words, are the gcc compilers installed on your computer?

Comment: Have a look at this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865976/r-packages-fail-to-compile-with-gcc)

Comment: I get:Error: object 'gcc' not found. Isn't the gcc part of the Rtools?

Comment: You need to install the gcc compilers link [http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/]

Comment: The link didn't work but google led me to this site: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php I installed it and restarted R but got the same response:gcc not found.

Comment: You need to set the path to the compilers, so that R knows where to look...see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install the `gcc` compilers and then you can install Rtools: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows.

Comment: I uninstalled both the compiler AND Rtools, then reinstalled the compiler and then reinnstalled Rtools adding the location of the compiler to the path. I still get "gcc no found".

Comment: Your problem is installing the gcc compilers, not Rtools.

Comment: ...impossible to give guidance without detailed description of what you have tried to do